# Saxparser: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: java, android, encoding, saxparser

I copied and edited some code, then ran this on my phone from Android Studio:

```
try {
         File myFile = new File(Storage.CONTENT_CACHE, "test.xml");
         if(!myFile.exists()) {
                String xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?><root>ä</root>";
                OutputStreamWriter wrt = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(myFile), "Cp1252");
                wrt.write(xml);
                wrt.close();
         }

         SAXParserFactory sf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
         SAXParser p = sf.newSAXParser();
         InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
         inputSource.setByteStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
         p.parse(inputSource, new DefaultHandler() {
                    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                        String test = String.valueOf(ch, start, length);
                        String s = "breakpt";
                    }
                });

      } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Can someone please explain why i'm getting the exception with message "not well-formed (invalid token)"?

Comment: The exception should tell you which token is invalid. Check [this link about diacritic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485955/%C3%A5-in-xml-file-is-valid-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to use `inputSource.setEncoding("windows-1252")` . Other libraries tries to detect charset but I couldn't find any robust one.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe xml doesn't accept any encoding, search for 'xml valid encodings'